# Controller still runs after $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

My issue is that I need to do a quick validation check when running my page’s Controller to check if the query parameters are valid. So right now I do this:

```
if (invalid params) {
    $state.go('state', {param: validParam}, {reload: true});
}

// Controller logic here to initialise the page
```

The behaviour here that I expect is that if the parameter is invalid, the entire Controller reloads with the valid parameter and everything is fine. What actually happens is that even after this `$state.go` line, the rest of the Controller still tries to run.

The only way I have managed to fix this is to do move the Controller logic into an `else` statement like so:

```
if (invalid params) {
    $state.go('state', {param: validParam}, {reload: true});
} else {
    // Controller logic here to initialise the page
}
```

This works, but I don’t find it ideal to move a lot of complicated logic into this `else` statement and I would expect the Controller to stop at the `$state.go` and reload the Controller…hence why I’m using `reload: true`.

So any ideas why this is not happening as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `state.go` is a function call, which is executed, but does not stop further processing. In case, we are in a function, we have control flow statements to stop execution, like `return`:

```
if (invalid params) {
    $state.go(‘state’, {param: validParam}, {reload: true});
    return;
}
```

And if we are not in function... it is plain JS set of operations.. we just should encapsulate them in such function:

```
var myFunction = function(){
    ...
    if (invalid params) {
        $state.go(‘state’, {param: validParam}, {reload: true});
        return;
    }
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: true true, I will wrap the controller into a function and get back to you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. I guess this is one of the reasons why I'm not a fan of Angular sometimes. I was thinking it was an Angular or UI-Router issue when in fact it's just a simple JavaScript issue. /facepalm

Comment: Great if that helped a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like :

```
$state.go($state.current, {param: validParam}, {reload: true});
```